# Set Button text with EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-button

Ohke here is the updated version:
Main xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.names.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:onClick="nextScreen"
        android:text="@string/Next" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:hint="Player B"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        android:ems="10" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:hint="Player A"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:ems="10" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Next-button calls method nextScreen in main:

```
public void nextScreen (View view)
{
    EditText ed1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    EditText ed2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    Intent intent = new Intent (this, ButtonsActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("string_A", ed1.getText());
    intent.putExtra("string_B", ed2.getText());
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And the onCreate in the 2nd activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_buttons);

    Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.player_A);
    Button btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.player_B);

    btn1.setText((CharSequence) getIntent().getExtras().get("string_A"));
    btn2.setText((CharSequence) getIntent().getExtras().get("string_B"));

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}
```

When I have input some text into the EditTexts, I press the next button and the app crashes.
Logcat-

```
05-04 15:21:54.922: E/AndroidRuntime(2025): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-04 15:21:54.922: E/AndroidRuntime(2025): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.names/com.example.names.ButtonsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-04 15:21:54.922: E/AndroidRuntime(2025):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2092)
05-04 15:21:54.922: E/AndroidRuntime(2025):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117)
05-04 15:21:54.922: E/AndroidRuntime(2025):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134)
05-04 15:21:54.922: E/AndroidRuntime(2025):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218)
05-04 15:21:54.922: E/AndroidRuntime(2025):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-04 15:21:54.922: E/AndroidRuntime(2025):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-04 15:21:54.922: E/AndroidRuntime(2025):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
05-04 15:21:54.922: E/AndroidRuntime(2025):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-04 15:21:54.922: E/AndroidRuntime(2025):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-04 15:21:54.922: E/AndroidRuntime(2025):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
05-04 15:21:54.922: E/AndroidRuntime(2025):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
05-04 15:21:54.922: E/AndroidRuntime(2025):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-04 15:21:54.922: E/AndroidRuntime(2025): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-04 15:21:54.922: E/AndroidRuntime(2025):     at com.example.names.ButtonsActivity.onCreate(ButtonsActivity.java:24)
05-04 15:21:54.922: E/AndroidRuntime(2025):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5047)
05-04 15:21:54.922: E/AndroidRuntime(2025):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
05-04 15:21:54.922: E/AndroidRuntime(2025):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2056)
05-04 15:21:54.922: E/AndroidRuntime(2025):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get views by id from a layout file which is not set as context view. You should set the Strings you want to show on the buttons as extra's to your `Intent` when calling the second activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("Str1", ed1.getText().toString());
intent.putExtra("Str2", ed2.getText().toString());
startActivity(intent);
```

And in your second activity:

```
btn1.setText(getIntent().getExtras().get("Str1"));
btn2.setTextgetIntent().getExtras().get("Str2"));
```

This is the best way to share the data between the activities.

Comment: Ohke I have updated my code but it still does not work correctly?

Comment: It crashes in the line 24 of the 2nd activity, which is   btn1.setText((CharSequence) getIntent().getExtras().get("string_A"));

Comment: There is no need to convert to CharSequence. You can just set a String to a Button

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("string_A", ed1.getText().toString()); //see .toString();
intent.putExtra("string_B", ed2.getText().toString());
```

and get like this.

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("string_A");
```

Comment: I seem to get the string fine, because when I go System.out.println(string_A) it shows whatever I typed in the EditText. But as soon as I try to btn.setText(string_A) it gives NullPointerException